# Best way to arrange variable sized DIVs within a fixed container

Tags: css, html

I have 9 divs with variable sizes. Each divs height and width must be multiple of 200 (they can be squire or rectangular).

A user can select any combination of divs so that they can be fit into a 800x800 box.Below are some possible arrangements of DIVs for 1st 2 rows (just for example).

Can you please lease suggest the best way of achieving it. I tried by setting all to float left, but that leaves some empty space.

[image: Possible arrangements]

Thanks,

Comment: have you seen jQuery isotop plugin...??? **[Click Here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)**

Comment: wow .. nice one ...let me check